# should the ASP.NET Server Control template exist in Visual Studio 2015 community edition?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, templates

I am trying to build a custom ASP.NET server control, but I am failing at the first hurdle.
All the tutorials have as their first step "Select the ASP.NET Server Control template".  My install of studio does not have that template. (VS 2015 community edition)  Ive tried several machines, with windows 7 to 10, and still no template.

Is this a matter of the template not being part of this edition, the template no longer being available, or something else that I am missing?

Comment: It might be handy to post a link to a screenshot showing where you're looking.

Comment: good thinking http://www.dracostandard.co.uk/images/ctemplate.jpg

Comment: you can follow the steps https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/893667/overview-of-user-controls-vs-custom-controls to create custom control using VS 2019.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're at the New Project screen. But ASP.NET Server Control isn't a project. You need to create a project (a class library or web application) and then right click your project in the Solution Explorer and expand Add, then click New Item. Expand Visual C# Items, Web, Web Forms, then you'll see Web Forms Server Control.

[image]

Comment: I am officially a moron- thanks I have spent days trying to find this!

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a new Windows Forms Application project. Right click the project and select the new item. Once selected, a pop-up window will appear. Click Web and you can see the Web Forms Server Control.

Comment: How exactly your answer is different with @mason's one?

Comment: well this really helped me because i already had winform project +1